# How do I remove the hyphens from \bridge and \hapto in chemmacros \ch environment?

Tags: chemmacros

I'd like to typeset a chemical formula with both bridging and hapticity. ([Specifically the title of this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/ejic.201301122)). There is a `coord-use-hyphen` option, but that only works inside the IUPAC environment, not the `\ch` environment.

Here is the (almost) working example of what I want:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

%Chemistry stuff
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\newcommand{\cheminfty}{\ensuremath{\infty}}


\begin{document}
\ch{^\cheminfty_{1}Zn[\trans-\bridge{2}(\hapto{3}:\hapto{3}-Ge9)]^{2-}}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, I have hyphens that should not exist after the `\bridge` and `\hapto`: Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: That's a bug that I found today. Load `chemmacros.sty` from https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/chemmacros/ where it's already fixed

Comment: BTW: it should be `\ch{^\cheminfty_{1}Zn[ "\trans-\bridge{2}(\hapto{3}:\hapto{3}-" Ge9)]^{2-}}` i.e. escaped input otherwise I'd expect strange things to happen... :)

Comment: @cgnieder How do I activate the `coord-use-hyphen` option now that I have the new file?

Comment: with `\chemsetup{iupac/coord-use-hyphen=false}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hyphens of the `\bridge` and `\hapto` commands can be disabled with

```
\chemsetup{iupac/coord-use-hyphen=false}
```

That the option belongs to the `iupac` class may be misleading but it doesn't mean that it only works inside the argument of the `\iupac` command.

Both `\hapto` and `\bridge` have a bug, though, which is fixed in v4.2a, that will be available on CTAN and TeX Live soon. The impatient can download it from [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/chemmacros/downloads/).

The `\trans-\bridge{2}(\hapto{3}:\hapto{3}-` part should probably be escaped from `chemformula`'s parsing mechanism: else the hyphens will be interpreted as single bonds and the numbers will be written as subscripts. Escaping is done by surrounding the relevant part in `"..."`, separated with blanks from the rest of the formula:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}[2013/10/31]
\chemsetup{iupac/coord-use-hyphen=false}
\begin{document}

\ch{^{$\infty$}1Zn[ "\trans-\bridge{2}(\hapto{3}:\hapto{3}-" Ge9)]^2-}

\bigskip

\ch{_{$\infty$}^1\{Zn[ "\trans-\bridge{2}(\hapto{3}:\hapto{3}-" Ge9)]\}^2-}

\end{document}
```

[image]